# Laptop creating noises when fully charged and plugged in

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

My laptop [Dell Inspiron 15r 5537](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-5537/overview), creates a buzzing sound when it is fully charged and still plugged in. As soon as I turn the charger off, the sound goes away. No sound comes when the laptop is charging below 100%. What could be the reason?

Comment: It could be the battery, the charger, or the power regulation subsystem in the laptop itself.  If you have another battery, use that instead. If you have another charger, try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely *not* the battery itself, which produces DC, not audio frequencies. Since it only occurs on full charge, it must be the charging system turning on and off. Dell offers great control of battery charging with the [Command - Power Manager](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ba/en/babsdt1/dell-command-power-manager-v2.2/userguide_dell/introduction?guid=guid-e818d92f-5e64-4af8-907a-8de626dea9cb&lang=en-us), which can be used to set times for charging. "[Advanced Charge](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ba/en/babsdt1/dell-command-power-manager-v2.2/userguide_dell/advanced-charge?guid=guid-f6b536ef-6812-4175-8641-8e7a31fa9ba7&lang=en-us) is an optional feature that prolongs the usable life of a system’s batteries by charging them to full capacity only once per day." Try enabling this feature, setting charging to end before you would use the computer, and the sound should not be heard again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop, but I have a gaming laptop from MSI, so it's not a DELL.

That noise was driving me crazy. It's difficult to describe what it sounds like, but it reminded me of the noise that failed HDD makes when reading from it... regular buzz and tic-tic.

However, I've opened up the BIOS and found this option on the "Advanced" page: **"ERP Lot 3 support"**. Set it to "Disable". This removes the automatic setting that saves energy (or protects battery) when fully charged (100%) and connected to the power supply (A/C).

This worked for me and the battery doesn't seem to suffer from it.

If this exact option is not available in your BIOS, try locating the power options (like ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) although I don't have this in my BIOS) and look for something similar.

---

I opened up the BIOS by restarting the laptop and keeping the "suppr" key pressed down (on the numpad). How you open up BISO may be different for your laptop brand and model.

**Warning**: if you're not sure about what you see in the BIOS, make further research online before changing these settings.

Comment: What is the model number of your laptop? Can you provide a screenshot of the BIOS page with this option on display?

Comment: Did you enable or disable "ERP lot 3 support"? Was it set to "Disable" already when you found it?